# Observer success and error test case issue from the component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

For my application component creating the unit test case, in component used the service to connect the rest api to get the data.

In the component subscribing the observable with success and error case, using mockservice I could achieve the success, error scenario can be covered using spon with return value. But I use both return value test case fails, rather than using mockserive tried with return value for success case but success case also fails.

> Component.ts

```
export class KpiComponent implements OnInit {

  public info: any[] = [];
  servicerError = false;
  constructor(private kpisService: KpisService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.kpisService.getKpiDetails().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.info = data;
          console.log('25 - Working');
        },
        (error) => {  console.log('27 - Error');  this.servicerError = true }
      );

    });
  }

}
```

> component.spec.ts

```
const info = [{ name: 'kpi' }];

    class MockKpisService {
      public getKpiDetails(): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.of(info);
      }

    }


    describe('KpiComponent', () => {
      let component: KpiComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<KpiComponent>;
      let kpisService: KpisService;
      let kpisService1: KpisService;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule, RouterModule, RouterTestingModule, BrowserModule, MatProgressBarModule, TableModule, MultiSelectModule, FormsModule, CalendarModule, DropdownModule, SpinnerModule, TooltipModule, HttpClientModule],
          declarations: [KpiComponent, DataTableComponent],
          providers: [{ provide: KpisService, useClass: MockKpisService }]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(KpiComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        kpisService = TestBed.get(KpisService);
        kpisService1 = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(KpisService);
        fixture.detectChanges();

      }));



      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });

      it('should List the Attachment', () => {
        //spyOn(kpisService, 'getKpiDetails').and.callThrough();
        expect(component.info).toBe(info);
        expect(component.servicerError).toBe(false);

      });

      it('should Error log displayed', () => {
        spyOn(kpisService, 'getKpiDetails').and.returnValue(Observable.throw({ status: 404 }));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.servicerError).toBe(true);
      });


    });
```

For the above code error block test failing.

For the blow code success test case failing, also service call happening through the component ngOnInit.

```
const info = [{ name: 'kpi' }];

describe('KpiComponent', () => {
  let component: KpiComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<KpiComponent>;
  let kpisService: KpisService;
  let kpisService1: KpisService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule, RouterModule, RouterTestingModule, BrowserModule, MatProgressBarModule, TableModule, MultiSelectModule, FormsModule, CalendarModule, DropdownModule, SpinnerModule, TooltipModule, HttpClientModule],
      declarations: [KpiComponent, DataTableComponent],
      providers: [KpisService]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(KpiComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    kpisService = TestBed.get(KpisService);
    kpisService1 = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(KpisService);
    fixture.detectChanges();

  }));



  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should List the Attachment', () => {
    spyOn(kpisService, 'getKpiDetails').and.returnValue(info);
    expect(component.info).toBe(info);
    expect(component.servicerError).toBe(false);

  });

  it('should Error log displayed', () => {
    spyOn(kpisService, 'getKpiDetails').and.returnValue(Observable.throw({ status: 404 }));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.servicerError).toBe(true);
  });


});
```

Comment: I don't want to be mean, but please, can you make proper sentences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, you can try with this.

```
it('should Error log displayed', () => {
        spyOn(kpisService, 'getKpiDetails').and.returnValue(Observable.throw({ status: 404 }));
        component.ngOnInit();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.servicerError).toBe(true);
        //verify the spy too
        expect(kpisService.getKpiDetails).toHaveBeenCalled();
 });
```

You should not be calling your real service in your unit tests. So, second method is not the way to go.

Comment: kpisServiceSpy.getKpiDetails.calls getting undefined error but without that  servicerError getting updated. thx

Comment: Can you try the updated code  in the answer for verifying your spy

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your error :

```js
it('should Error log displayed', () => {
  spyOn(kpisService, 'getKpiDetails').and.returnValue(Observable.throw({ status: 404 }));
  kpisService.getKpiDetails().subscribe(response => null, error => {
    expect(component.servicerError).toBe(true);
  });
  fixture.detectChanges();
  component.ngOnInit();
});
```

If it doesn't work, rty with a timeout on the `ngOnInit` call.